# I want to move ubuntu to a different partition

Tags: partitioning, storage

So I have 3 volumes a hdd with 20,1 GB, a ssd with 79 GB and another ssd with 27 GB, and I Want to move the ubuntu files to another partition , I have ubuntu 22.04 , and it keeps saying it's has very little space, and so I wanna move it

Comment: Please edit your original question to describe with more details what you have and what you want. Otherwise we can only guess. - One way to show what you have is to connect all the relevant drives and run the following command line, `lsblk -o name,size,fstype,label,mountpoint,model` and put the output into your original question. Indent each line 4 spaces to render it as `code`.

Comment: Please include the version of Ubuntu in your [edits to the question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1422909/edit).

Comment: Are you willing to use command lines in a terminal window? In that case, please connect all the relevant drives and run the following command line, `lsblk -o name,size,fstype,label,mountpoint,model` and put the output into your original question. Indent each line 4 spaces to render it as code. That will show us, who can help you, how your drives are configured, and it will be possible to start a dialog about the possible alternatives to move Ubuntu.